# Oracle: Loop over partitions / groups and their subpartitions / groups

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, partitioning

I would like to know if it is possible to achieve the steps below in PL / SQL.

Please note that I use the word "partition" when I mean "put rows with a certain condition together" because a) I would like to avoid the word "group" because it combines rows in SQL, b) my research so far led me to think that the "PARTITION BY" clause is possibly what I want:

```
1. Select rows based on a long query with many joins, 
partition the results based on a certain column value of type LONG.

2. Loop through each row of a partition and partition again, 
based on another column of type VARCHAR. 
Do that for every partition. 

3. Loop through each row of the resulting sub-partition, compare multiple columns 
with predefined values, set a boolean column to true or false based on the result. 
Do that for every sub-partition.
```

It would be really easy to do for me in a normal programming language, such as Java. But can I do that in PL/SQL? If so, what would be a good approach?

Comment: Hello as you said that its a long running query, deep level partitions will impact a lot on performance. Yes it is achievable but i would not recommend it.

Comment: You need to provide some sample data, and example of what the result should be, and sample code you have tried. However, if performance is currently an issue, adding more PL/SQL probably won't help. There's a possibility you can do this entirely in SQL, which will be your fastest option.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. With "long" I mean complicated with many ANDs and ORs. Performance is not an issue at all, nor something I worry about. What I'd like to know is if I can code this in SQL principally. I'll try to post some example data later.

Comment: As far as I understand you want to set the value of a boolean column depending on the value of other columns. I don't understand what you want to achieve with "partitions". Can you explain why you want to group/partition your rows? Why don't you traverse your table row by row and set the boolean column? This maybe far less fast then using SQL but will be at least as fast as looping through the table in a way depenging on some column values.